# Divide document by two independent columns

Tags: columns

I'm looking to create a document divided into two columns:

the first column (left) being dedicated to text and the right column to images and graphs (like Spivak's Calculus, as an example). Whenever I fulfil the left column I should expect the text to remain at the left column of the next page and not writing on the right column.

I know how to make two columns in latex using    mulicols    , but it would be non-practical to break columns.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please have a look into `paracols` package

Comment: You'd better  use single column and a larger `\marginparwidth`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I tried 'paracols' but the columns are not parallel. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? I just did the simplest code using 'paracol', 'leftcolumn*' and 'rightcolumn*'

Comment: @Bernard , but if I change the margin, doesn't it mean that I can't use the margin for drawing graphs? I need the text to have that margin, yes, but I also want to use that empty space for graphing. Thanks!

Comment: @TelmoVianaVaz: You don't show any code, it's difficult to say what goes wrong then...

Comment: You can put the graphs in the margin with `marginnote`.

Comment: thank you, @Bernard . That solved my problem! How do I give you reputation without you making an answer?

Comment: That is unimportant. The main point is I'm glad to feel helpful from time to time…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.